# Django admin append inline to list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin, clicking on **id** field, I can access the object an correctly see the **MaterialInline** data.

I get the same data in the **list_display** by the **get_materiale** method.

```
class MaterialInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Materiale

class OreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('id','who','when','get_materiale')

    inlines = [MaterialeInLine]  

    def get_materiale(self, obj):
        return obj.rif_materiale_set.values_list()
```

It would it be possible to **replace** the **get_materiale** by the **MaterialInline** in list_display ?

I'm using django 1.9.6

Comment: The `inlines` option affects the change view, and `list_display` affects the changelist view. It doesn't make sense to try to use the inline in `list_display`.

Comment: It will help to allow the direct editing of rows linked to header, without getting in the specific page. Would you say that I need to trick it with ajax in template?

Comment: You might be able to add that functionality using ajax, but I don't think it would be straight forward.